# default value while serialize/deserialize json/object using GSON

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am using GSON for serialize and deserialize JSON/JAva Object for one of my application. I am using serializeNulls as some of my value need to be send as null to web service while some I don't want to be NULL. So what I tried in my setter/getter for which I don't need null that I have check that value is null or not, if its null then set the "" blank for it. But still when I am deserializing my object to json using gson.toJson() method its giving me null value for those.

```
private String mID;

public void setId(final String id) {
    if(id == null) {
        id = "";
    }
    mID = id;
}

public String getId() {
    if(mID == null) {
        mID = "";
    }
    return mID;
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

Any idea how can i avoid null for some of the fields and set blank "" using setter/getter method or some other way.

Comment: Gson doesn't use getters to access fields to serialize. Just make sure mID is never null. You made that sure in the setter, but maybe you have a constructor or another method setting (or leaving)  it to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using default value of `mID` and proper setter method

sample code:

```
class MyId{
    private String mID="";

    public void setId(final String id) {
        if(id != null) {
            mID = id;
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mID;
    }
}

...
//JSON string to Object
MyId myId=new Gson().fromJson("{}", MyId.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(myId));

...
// Object to JSON string
MyId myId = new MyId();
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(myId));
```

output:

```
{
   "mID": ""
}
```